# How to solve certificate issue for internal URL in Chrome

Tags: certificate, iis

When entering the following internal URL (changed a bit for privacy) in Chrome:

```
https://pms/WebClient/CRMclient.aspx
```

I get Chrome's message for a certificate mismatch:

```
This is probably not the site you are looking for!
You attempted to reach pms, but instead you actually reached a server identifying itself as *.mydomain.int.
```

(Of course, if I hit `Proceed`, it will go to the page I want.)

I then test

```
ping pms
ping pms.mydomain.int
```

And I get the same IP address as a result, so I change the URL from

```
https://pms/WebClient/CRMclient.aspx
```

to

```
https://pms.mydomain.int/WebClient/CRMclient.aspx
```

to see if now the security warning goes away, but I get an `HTTP 404` error.

If I enter, however, the IP address in the URL:
https://10.10.10.10/WebClient/CRMclient.aspx

It finds the page, but with the security warning.

So my question is how do I get out of this problem?
Is there way to tell Chrome to ignore this issue for internal URLs?
Or even better, for a specific URL?
Or something on the server side (IIS)?

My restrictions:

- It is Chrome
- I can't change the directory structure
- I can't change the page code

My freedoms:

- I can make the URL be whatever I want, as long as it gets straight to
  the page without showing the warning.

Note, this is on Windows Server 2008 R2 so it must be IIS 7.5.

Thanks for your help. If you suggest anything on the IIS side, please help me fully by being specific. I don't know IIS.

Comment: pms.WebClient? WebClient is the name of a folder. pms.WebClient doesn't resolve to anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`https://pms.mydomain.int/WebClient/CRMclient.aspx` should work fine. Try to find out why you get a 404.

Check the [sub-status code](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/943891) for the 404 in the IIS logs then try to fix the problem.

Check your site bindings as well.

Comment: Will try that, thanks. But why would it give me a 404 with the full domain name and not with the IP address (or the pms alias)?

Comment: It was some other issue with url routing but you were the closest. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your security needs you can try disabling "Phishing and malware protection" in the settings of Google Chrome. Just uncheck the box here:

Settings > Advanced Settings > Privacy > [checked-box] Enable phi...

[How to Disable Phishing and Malware Protection](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95572)

A more elegant solution would be to have the ability to white-list specific URL's. Unfortunately I don't believe that this is possible in Chrome currently.

Comment: Jacob, I saw that setting, but I don't know how to do it just for internal addresses.

Comment: I don't think that that is possible at this time. It seems that currently it's either all or nothing. Perhaps you can set up a separate browser profile just for internal use?

Comment: That wouldn't be practical here, but thanks for your help!